# I wrote this image search command for discord.py and i dont know how to make it look good

Tags: image, discord, discord.py, bots

[this is what i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDsdR.png)

[this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn08Q.png)

[It also sends this in the start of every search for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6ldE.png)

```
from google_images_download import google_images_download


@client.command()
async def image(ctx, query):
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={query}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    image_elements = soup.find_all('img')
    url_list = [image['src'] for image in image_elements]
    current_index = 0
    message = await ctx.send(url_list[current_index])
    await message.add_reaction('◀️')
    await message.add_reaction('▶️')
    while True:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.message.id == message.id)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '▶️':
            current_index = (current_index + 1) % len(url_list)
            await message.edit(content=url_list[current_index])
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '◀️':
            current_index = (current_index - 1) % len(url_list)
            await message.edit(content=url_list[current_index])
        await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```

I tried to change the

```
    message = await ctx.send(url_list[current_index])
```

into this

```
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Image Viewer", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_image(url=url_list[current_index])
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was good except sometimes the url_list[current_index] returs an str.

I made it so the first picture will be an embed, the rest is on you. Use the same logic and you will have no problem.

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def image(ctx, query):
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={query}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    image_elements = soup.find_all('img')
    url_list = [image['src'] for image in image_elements]
    current_index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Image",description=query)
            embed.set_image(url = url_list[current_index])
            message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            break
        except:
            current_index += 1
    await message.add_reaction('◀️')
    await message.add_reaction('▶️')
    while True:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.message.id == message.id)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '▶️':
            current_index = (current_index + 1) % len(url_list)
            await message.edit(content=url_list[current_index])
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '◀️':
            current_index = (current_index - 1) % len(url_list)
            await message.edit(content=url_list[current_index])
        await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```

Comment: Also you can do further designing on the embed.

Comment: How would I get it to embed to first 100 images and not show a link?

Comment: You implement the same `while True` + `try - except` logic in your `if - else` statement.

Comment: first time using the module could you do it for me?

Answer (score -1):

An advice of mine is try to understand the code why does it work etc. ask questions in the comments , I'll try and answer them. And don't just copy the code , write it down for yourself and you will start to understand it.

Here is the full code:

```
@client.command()
async def image(ctx, query):
    response = requests.get(f"https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q={query}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    image_elements = soup.find_all('img')
    url_list = [image['src'] for image in image_elements]
    current_index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Image",description=query)
            embed.set_image(url = url_list[current_index])
            message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            break
        except:
            current_index += 1
    await message.add_reaction('◀️')
    await message.add_reaction('▶️')
    while True:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.message.id == message.id)
        if str(reaction.emoji) == '▶️':
            current_index = (current_index + 1) % len(url_list)
            while True:
                try:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Image",description=query)
                    embed.set_image(url = url_list[current_index])
                    await message.edit(content="",embed=embed)
                    break
                except:
                    current_index += 1
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '◀️':
            current_index = (current_index - 1) % len(url_list)
            while True:
                try:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Image",description=query)
                    embed.set_image(url = url_list[current_index])
                    await message.edit(content="",embed=embed)
                    break
                except:
                    current_index -= 1
        await message.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
```